# SonataAdmin child admin route visible in debug but not found

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

php bin/console debug:router |grep postboxmessage

```
  pt__RG__admin_mea_postbox_postboxmessage_list                ANY        ANY      ANY    /admin/mea/postbox/postboxmessage/list                                                 
  pl__RG__admin_mea_postbox_postboxmessage_list                ANY        ANY      ANY    /pl/admin/mea/postbox/postboxmessage/list                                              
  en__RG__admin_mea_postbox_postboxmessage_list                ANY        ANY      ANY    /en/admin/mea/postbox/postboxmessage/list                                              
  pt__RG__admin_mea_postbox_postboxmessage_create              ANY        ANY      ANY    /admin/mea/postbox/postboxmessage/create                                               
  pl__RG__admin_mea_postbox_postboxmessage_create              ANY        ANY      ANY    /pl/admin/mea/postbox/postboxmessage/create                                            
  en__RG__admin_mea_postbox_postboxmessage_create              ANY        ANY      ANY    /en/admin/mea/postbox/postboxmessage/create                                            
  pt__RG__admin_mea_postbox_postboxmessage_batch               ANY        ANY      ANY    /admin/mea/postbox/postboxmessage/batch                                                
  pl__RG__admin_mea_postbox_postboxmessage_batch               ANY        ANY      ANY    /pl/admin/mea/postbox/postboxmessage/batch                                             
  en__RG__admin_mea_postbox_postboxmessage_batch               ANY        ANY      ANY    /en/admin/mea/postbox/postboxmessage/batch                                             
  pt__RG__admin_mea_postbox_postboxmessage_edit                ANY        ANY      ANY    /admin/mea/postbox/postboxmessage/{id}/edit                                            
  pl__RG__admin_mea_postbox_postboxmessage_edit                ANY        ANY      ANY    /pl/admin/mea/postbox/postboxmessage/{id}/edit                                         
  en__RG__admin_mea_postbox_postboxmessage_edit                ANY        ANY      ANY    /en/admin/mea/postbox/postboxmessage/{id}/edit                                         
  pt__RG__admin_mea_postbox_postboxmessage_delete              ANY        ANY      ANY    /admin/mea/postbox/postboxmessage/{id}/delete                                          
  pl__RG__admin_mea_postbox_postboxmessage_delete              ANY        ANY      ANY    /pl/admin/mea/postbox/postboxmessage/{id}/delete                                       
  en__RG__admin_mea_postbox_postboxmessage_delete              ANY        ANY      ANY    /en/admin/mea/postbox/postboxmessage/{id}/delete                                       
  pt__RG__admin_mea_postbox_postboxmessage_export              ANY        ANY      ANY    /admin/mea/postbox/postboxmessage/export                                               
  pl__RG__admin_mea_postbox_postboxmessage_export              ANY        ANY      ANY    /pl/admin/mea/postbox/postboxmessage/export                                            
  en__RG__admin_mea_postbox_postboxmessage_export              ANY        ANY      ANY    /en/admin/mea/postbox/postboxmessage/export                                            
  pt__RG__admin_mea_postbox_postboxmessage_send                ANY        ANY      ANY    /admin/mea/postbox/postboxmessage/send                                                 
  pl__RG__admin_mea_postbox_postboxmessage_send                ANY        ANY      ANY    /pl/admin/mea/postbox/postboxmessage/send                                              
  en__RG__admin_mea_postbox_postboxmessage_send                ANY        ANY      ANY    /en/admin/mea/postbox/postboxmessage/send                                              
  pt__RG__admin_app_postboxthread_postboxmessage_list          ANY        ANY      ANY    /admin/app/postboxthread/{id}/postboxmessage/list                                      
  pl__RG__admin_app_postboxthread_postboxmessage_list          ANY        ANY      ANY    /pl/admin/app/postboxthread/{id}/postboxmessage/list                                   
  en__RG__admin_app_postboxthread_postboxmessage_list          ANY        ANY      ANY    /en/admin/app/postboxthread/{id}/postboxmessage/list                                   
  pt__RG__admin_app_postboxthread_postboxmessage_create        ANY        ANY      ANY    /admin/app/postboxthread/{id}/postboxmessage/create                                    
  pl__RG__admin_app_postboxthread_postboxmessage_create        ANY        ANY      ANY    /pl/admin/app/postboxthread/{id}/postboxmessage/create                                 
  en__RG__admin_app_postboxthread_postboxmessage_create        ANY        ANY      ANY    /en/admin/app/postboxthread/{id}/postboxmessage/create                                 
  pt__RG__admin_app_postboxthread_postboxmessage_batch         ANY        ANY      ANY    /admin/app/postboxthread/{id}/postboxmessage/batch                                     
  pl__RG__admin_app_postboxthread_postboxmessage_batch         ANY        ANY      ANY    /pl/admin/app/postboxthread/{id}/postboxmessage/batch                                  
  en__RG__admin_app_postboxthread_postboxmessage_batch         ANY        ANY      ANY    /en/admin/app/postboxthread/{id}/postboxmessage/batch                                  
  pt__RG__admin_app_postboxthread_postboxmessage_edit          ANY        ANY      ANY    /admin/app/postboxthread/{id}/postboxmessage/{childId}/edit                            
  pl__RG__admin_app_postboxthread_postboxmessage_edit          ANY        ANY      ANY    /pl/admin/app/postboxthread/{id}/postboxmessage/{childId}/edit                         
  en__RG__admin_app_postboxthread_postboxmessage_edit          ANY        ANY      ANY    /en/admin/app/postboxthread/{id}/postboxmessage/{childId}/edit                         
  pt__RG__admin_app_postboxthread_postboxmessage_delete        ANY        ANY      ANY    /admin/app/postboxthread/{id}/postboxmessage/{childId}/delete                          
  pl__RG__admin_app_postboxthread_postboxmessage_delete        ANY        ANY      ANY    /pl/admin/app/postboxthread/{id}/postboxmessage/{childId}/delete                       
  en__RG__admin_app_postboxthread_postboxmessage_delete        ANY        ANY      ANY    /en/admin/app/postboxthread/{id}/postboxmessage/{childId}/delete                       
  pt__RG__admin_app_postboxthread_postboxmessage_show          ANY        ANY      ANY    /admin/app/postboxthread/{id}/postboxmessage/{childId}/show                            
  pl__RG__admin_app_postboxthread_postboxmessage_show          ANY        ANY      ANY    /pl/admin/app/postboxthread/{id}/postboxmessage/{childId}/show                         
  en__RG__admin_app_postboxthread_postboxmessage_show          ANY        ANY      ANY    /en/admin/app/postboxthread/{id}/postboxmessage/{childId}/show                         
  pt__RG__admin_app_postboxthread_postboxmessage_export        ANY        ANY      ANY    /admin/app/postboxthread/{id}/postboxmessage/export                                    
  pl__RG__admin_app_postboxthread_postboxmessage_export        ANY        ANY      ANY    /pl/admin/app/postboxthread/{id}/postboxmessage/export                                 
  en__RG__admin_app_postboxthread_postboxmessage_export        ANY        ANY      ANY    /en/admin/app/postboxthread/{id}/postboxmessage/export
```

php bin/console router:match  /en/admin/app/postboxthread/{id}/postboxmessage/list

[OK] Route "en__RG__admin_app_postboxthread_postboxmessage_list" matches

```
+--------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Property     | Value                                                                                     |
+--------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Route Name   | en__RG__admin_app_postboxthread_postboxmessage_list                                       |
| Path         | /en/admin/app/postboxthread/{id}/postboxmessage/list                                      |
| Path Regex   | #^/en/admin/app/postboxthread/(?P<id>[^/]++)/postboxmessage/list$#sD                      |
| Host         | ANY                                                                                       |
| Host Regex   |                                                                                           |
| Scheme       | ANY                                                                                       |
| Method       | ANY                                                                                       |
| Requirements | NO CUSTOM                                                                                 |
| Class        | Symfony\Component\Routing\Route                                                           |
| Defaults     | _controller: Mea\PostBoxBundle\Sonata\Controller\PostBoxMessageCrudController::listAction |
|              | _locale: en                                                                               |
|              | _sonata_admin: mea.postbox.sonata.admin.thread|mea.postbox.sonata.admin.message           |
|              | _sonata_name: admin_app_postboxthread_postboxmessage_list                                 |
| Options      | compiler_class: Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCompiler                                   |
+--------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

This example partial work, but this route I guessed :)

PostBoxThreadAdmin

```
 /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function configureTabMenu(MenuItemInterface $menu, $action, AdminInterface $childAdmin = null): void
    {
        if (!$childAdmin && !in_array($action, ['edit'])) {
            return;
        }

        $admin = $this->isChild() ? $this->getParent() : $this;

        $id = $admin->getRequest()->get('id');

        if ($this->isGranted('EDIT')) {
            $menu->addChild('Edit Thread', [
                'uri' => $admin->generateUrl('edit', ['id' => $id])
            ]);
        }

        $menu->addChild('Messages',
            $admin->generateMenuUrl('mea.postbox.sonata.admin.message.list', ['id' => $id])
        );

    }
```

When i try

```
$menu->addChild('Messages',
            $admin->generateMenuUrl('mea.postbox.sonata.admin.message', ['id' => $id])
        );
```

get

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("unable to find the route `mea.postbox.sonata.admin.thread|mea.postbox.sonata.admin.message`").
```

try

```
   $menu->addChild('Messages',
            $admin->generateMenuUrl('mea.postbox.sonata.admin.thread|mea.postbox.sonata.admin.message', ['id' => $id])
        );
```

get

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("unable to find the route `mea.postbox.sonata.admin.thread|mea.postbox.sonata.admin.thread|mea.postbox.sonata.admin.message`").
```

try

```
  $menu->addChild('Messages',
            $admin->generateMenuUrl('admin_app_postboxthread_postboxmessage_list', ['id' => $id])
        );
```

get

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("unable to find the route `mea.postbox.sonata.admin.thread.admin_app_postboxthread_postboxmessage_list`").
```

When i use

$menu->addChild('Messages',
                $admin->generateMenuUrl('mea.postbox.sonata.admin.message.list', ['id' => $id])
            );

child panel is shown but when i create new and save - i get

```
unable to find the route `mea.postbox.sonata.admin.thread|mea.postbox.sonata.admin.message.send`

RuntimeException
in vendor/sonata-project/admin-bundle/src/Route/DefaultRouteGenerator.php (line 109)
in vendor/sonata-project/admin-bundle/src/Route/DefaultRouteGenerator.php->generateMenuUrl (line 60)
in vendor/Mea/PostBoxBundle/Sonata/Admin/PostBoxMessageAdmin.php->generateUrl (line 190)
in vendor/sonata-project/admin-bundle/src/Admin/AbstractAdmin.php->configureFormFields (line 1267)
in vendor/sonata-project/admin-bundle/src/Admin/AbstractAdmin.php->defineFormBuilder (line 1254)
in vendor/sonata-project/admin-bundle/src/Admin/AbstractAdmin.php->getFormBuilder (line 2980)
in vendor/sonata-project/admin-bundle/src/Admin/AbstractAdmin.php->buildForm (line 1311)
in vendor/sonata-project/admin-bundle/src/Controller/CRUDController.php->getForm (line 336)
in vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php->editAction (line 149)
in vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php->handleRaw (line 66)
in vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php->handle (line 188)
Kernel->handle(object(Request))
in public/index.php (line 37)
    Request::setTrustedHosts(explode(',', $trustedHosts));}$kernel = new Kernel($env, $debug);$request = Request::createFromGlobals();$response = $kernel->handle($request);$response->send();$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

So Sonata try use route  _sonata_admin: mea.postbox.sonata.admin.thread|mea.postbox.sonata.admin.message  but is not accessible

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
'uri' => str_replace('{id}',$id,'/admin/app/property/{id}/property-media/list')
```

If you need the route, you can find it with:

```
bin/console debug:router
```